# Running MPI fortran code sample make file

Tags: linux, makefile, fortran

I am given a code to run on clusters, and the .sh file content is as below:

```
compiler  =  mpifort

in8.3     =  mac-ns-2d.8.3.f90

out       =  a.out

inc       =  hypre/include

libs      =  src/hypre/lib

opts      =  -O4

8.3:
    $(compiler) $(opts) -I$(inc) $(in8.3) -o $(out) -L$(libs) -lHYPRE -lm -lstdc++
```

I see what is the first line, which is my compiler mpifortran, but what is the second line meaning, in8.3?
I also know the meaning for out, inc, libs, but what is the purpose of opts -04 and what does 8.3: mean and the line after that?

Comment: What kind of code is this? It looks like a Makefile to me...

Comment: It is a makefile for an MPI fortran code

Comment: Tagging the question appropriately will help: I recommend `Makefile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard Unix Makefile, but it's using weird variable names.

The first few lines are all assignments:

```
compiler  =  mpifort
in8.3     =  mac-ns-2d.8.3.f90
out       =  a.out
inc       =  hypre/include
libs      =  src/hypre/lib
opts      =  -O4
```

These basically assign strings to variables. For example, later in the Makefile, one may use `$(out)` and get `a.out` substituted in.  This is a common way of collecting all things that may need tweaking later such as what compiler to use, what compilation flags one uses and other things.

You asked specifically about `opts`.  This variable's value is `-O4` which is a compiler flag that enables "optimization level 4" (usually the highest optimization level, but check your compiler's manual).

The next two lines is a target and a rule for building the target:

```
8.3:
    $(compiler) $(opts) -I$(inc) $(in8.3) -o $(out) -L$(libs) -lHYPRE -lm -lstdc++
```

The second of these two lines should be indented with a single tab.

I'm not going to describe what a target is and what a rule for making a target is, other than saying that `make` will "make" the first target of the Makefile using the specified rule. Targets may have dependencies (other targets) that needs to be considered before running the rules for the top target. This is not the case here.

As you can see, the last line uses the variables previously defined to compile the program.

Running `make` will produce:

```
$ make
mpifort -O4 -Ihypre/include mac-ns-2d.8.3.f90 -o a.out -Lsrc/hypre/lib -lHYPRE -lm -lstdc++
mpifort: not found
*** Error 1 in /tmp/shell-ksh.l1TMWqET (Makefile:14 '8.3')
```

Since I don't have `mpifort` (the compiler) installed, I'm getting an error message, but you can also see the command that `make` tried to execute.  This corresponds to the last line of this Makefile with all variables substituted by their values.

I'd recommend seeking out a tutorial on `make` and Makefiles.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your keywords helped me to google some one my questions, and now I have a better understanding. Just a couple of questions now:
I got it that the first lines are just string variable assignments. And could read on optimization levels [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/stud.10/819-0492/3_options.html) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

And based on what I found the last two lines are target and recipe(which recipe is indented by tab)

and when we wanna use a parameter referenced before, in recipe we use $ ...

Comment: ...But here my questions

What is 8.3: specification as target, should it match the 8.3 part of in8.3 defined above it? how this name shows itself? where? what happens if I change it to some OTHERNAME: ?

+does the order of $() matter? like putting -L$(libs) before $(out) or $(opts) at the end? where can I read on the proper ordering of recipe?

+what does the last three words mean? i.e. -lHYPRE -lm -lstdc++

I know HYPRE is a library I need for my linear solvers, but what is the "l" behind it and the other two words?
I think libstdc++ is c++ library, but why to include here

Thanks

Comment: @soes Usually, the name of the target is the name of a file (which the next line creates or updates), but it doesn't need to be. `make` updates the target if the file is out of date or does not exist. As for the ordering of the compiler's options; they can matter, depending on the compiler. That has nothing to do with `make`. `-l` is a flag that tells the compiler to link a certain library. Again, refer to the manual of the compiler.

Comment: @soes `HYPRE` is some 3rd party library, `m` is the standard math library, and `stdc++` is the standard C++ library (I'm assuming that `HYPRE` or something else is using C++ even though the main program is a Fortran 90 program).

Comment: @soes If you change the target from `8.3:` to `$(out):` and run `make` you will notice that it won't rebuild the `a.out` file if it already exists. If you write the target as `$(out): $(in8.3)` (this introduces a dependency between the target and the file whose name is stored in `$(in8.3)`), then the `a.out` file will be rebuilt only if the Fortran 90 source file is changed in any way.

Comment: @soes That's kind of the heart of what a Makefile is about.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the format and way of using Makefile here is quite strange. It's OK, but it could be done slightly different way.

Let's say you have file: **mac-ns-2d.8.3.f90**

```
program main
  use mpi

  integer error, id, p
  call MPI_Init ( error )
  call MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, p, error )
  call MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, id, error )
  write (*,*) 'Hello: ', id, '/', p
  call MPI_Finalize ( error )
end
```

Then, you can slightly modify your Makefile to be more "elegant"

```
compiler  =  mpifort
#I am commenting out these two to make compilation go trhough
#inc       =  hypre/include
#libs      =  src/hypre/lib
opts      =  -O4

a.out: mac-ns-2d.8.3.f90
    $(compiler) $(opts) -I$(inc) -L$(libs) -lm -lstdc++ $< -o $@

clean:
    -rm a.out
```

And the, you can simply make the target and run the code

```
> make
mpifort -O4 -I -L -lm -lstdc++ mac-ns-2d.8.3.f90 -o a.out
> mpirun -np 2 ./a.out
 Hello:            0 /           2
 Hello:            1 /           2
```

I, personally, would have changed this line

```
a.out: mac-ns-2d.8.3.f90
```

To something more suitable, like

```
name_of_my_executable: mac-ns-2d.8.3.f90
```